# How to say "X movies" that are movies about X

Tags: words, usage, particle-の, word-usage

How do I say 'X movies' in Japanese? By this I mean a movie about X, not X made that movie. An example to illustrate what I mean is:

> There are a lot of **Steve Jobs movies**

It is clear that Steve Jobs himself did not make the movies. How I thought to phrase this would be スティーブ・ジョブズの映画。But doesn't this mean 'Steve Jobs' movies', indicating Steve Jobs is in possession of the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *But doesn't this mean 'Steve Jobs' movies', indicating Steve Jobs is in possession of the movie?*

It could, because the Japanese `[noun]の[work]` can casually denote every kind of association between the noun and work (but I think "[noun] movies" is highly ambiguous, too).

村上春樹の小説 is likely to be "a novel *by* Haruki Murakami", but 涼宮ハルヒの小説 must be "a novel *featuring* [Haruhi Suzumiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Haruhi_Suzumiya_light_novels)", and 米澤嘉博の漫画 should be "manga *owned by* [Yoshihiro Yonezawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro_Yonezawa)". How about 村上春樹の映画? Maybe he made, performed, became the subject, or provided the original work. (Only the last thing is what he really did, as far as I know.)

If you want to tell "movies about Steve Jobs" without misunderstanding, you can have some workarounds:

> スティーブ・ジョブズについての映画
>   スティーブ・ジョブズに関する映画
>   スティーブ・ジョブズを扱った映画
>   スティーブ・ジョブズを撮った映画 (if filmed while he was living)
>   etc.

By the by, if you want to categorize them as a "Steve Jobs movies" genre, you can say:

> スティーブ・ジョブズもの（の映画）

Comment: @CipherBot Note that they are "workaround".  They are all a bit too stiff and might sound a bit unnatural depending on the situation.  When Japanese talk about クリント・イーストウッドの映画, we just don't distinguish a film featuring Eastwood and a film directed by him.  Ah, perhaps we say イーストウッド主演の映画 (featuring,) イーストウッド監督の映画 (direction,) and イーストウッドの伝記映画 (biographical film) [though the last one doesn't really exist as far as I know]