# How to say "written by"

Tags: grammar

In a shop I want to ask "Are there any books by Haruki Murakami?" I don't know the natural way to express **by** in this context.

I thought maybe I could use the passive form like this:

> 村上に書かれる本がありますか。

But having to explicitly use the verb 書く seems unnecessary. I assume that

> *村上に本がありますか。

is just incorrect grammar.

I thought maybe

> 村上作がありますか。

might be correct, but a google search for 村上作が returned no results. What is the natural way to ask this question?

Comment: FWIW http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32868/7810

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We say usually 村上春樹の本はありますか?. "written by" is translated as "によって書かれた and ～著作の" but we usually omit them.

Answer (score 2):

To less frequently than 村上春樹の本はありますか?, we say 村上春樹のありますか？ or　村上春樹が書いたの（置いて）ありますか？