# Hi everyone, I was wondering how you say by____ in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I am doing a presentation for my Japanese class, and I want to say: by (insert name)
For example:
Introduction to Japan
By Emma

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33876/how-to-say-written-by

Answer (score 1):

I guess we don't write this "by" in Japanese.

You can put "Erica 著" if it were a book, or "Erica 作" if it were a piece of art, but I've never seen Japanese people put any Japanese word meaning "by" in presentation slides. Keeping it in English like "日本の紹介 by Tanaka Hanako" sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I’m gonna add an answer to this. If you use an iPhone and have Apple Music, you’ll see that at the end of lyrics there is a line:

> 作成: XXX(such as 作成: 清水依与吏)

Which denotes the producer of the music. That’s probably the most native way to translate “by XXX”

[image]